# What is the simplest way to count the occurrences of different numbers in a sorted array?

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm

For example there is a sorted array `[1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,5,5]`, without using map/hashtable, just using index, how to check whether all different numbers have the same count? This example should return `False`, while `[1,1,3,3,6,6]` should return `True`. What would be the code like in Python?

This is what I have, but am looking for some cleaner way to this:

```
def hasSameOccurenceCount(deck):
    preNum = sys.maxsize
    preCount = 1
    count = 1
    preNum = deck[0]
    for i in range(1, len(deck)):
        if preNum != deck[i]:
            if preCount == 1:
                preCount = count
                count = 1
                preNum = deck[i]
            elif preCount != count:
                return False
            else:
                preCount = count
                count = 1
                preNum = deck[i]
        else:
            count += 1
    if count != preCount:
        return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use groupby and compare the size of the first group to the size of every other group:

```
from itertools import groupby

def sameCounts(A):
    groups = groupby(A)
    return all(len(other)==len(first) for _,(*first,) in groups 
                                      for _,(*other,) in groups)


print(sameCounts([1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,5,5])) # False
print(sameCounts([1,1,3,3,6,6])) # True
```

If you're not allowed to use libraries, you can divide the list in chunks based on the number of distinct values.  All the values should start and end on chunk boundaries.  Any discrepancy would cause a desynchronization.

```
def sameCounts(A):
    count = len(set(A))
    chunk,rest = divmod(len(A),count)
    if rest : return False
    return all(A[i]==A[i+chunk-1] for i in range(0,len(A),chunk))
```

You could make this a bit shorter, albeit less efficient, by comparing striding subscripts.

```
def sameCounts(A):
    chunk,rest = divmod(len(A),len(set(A)))
    return not rest and A[::chunk]==A[chunk-1::chunk]
```

Answer (score 1):

This one is fairly simple:

```
def hasSameOccurenceCount(deck):
    return all(
        deck.count(x) == deck.count(deck[0])
        for x in deck
    )
```

Or if with "map/hashtable" you meant a `dict` for counting each element, and the `map` function and a `set` for collecting the different counts (there can only be O(√n) many) are allowed:

```
def hasSameOccurenceCount(deck):
    return len(set(map(deck.count, deck))) < 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  def sameCount(arr):
     temp = []
     for i in range(len(arr)):
        if temp.count(arr[i]) == 0:
           temp.append(arr[i])
     counts = []
     for i in range(len(temp)):
        counts.append(arr.count(temp[i]))
     if len(arr) != 0:
        if counts.count(counts[0]) == len(counts):
           return True
        else:
           return False
     else:
        return True
```

This code is incredibly crude. I started a year ago and am not that good but it works. If you're looking for efficiency, do not use this.

Comment: Sorry, yeah the index in line 9 was 1. I've been using R lately so I forgot that python indexes in 0s.

Comment: Still fails `sameCount([])`, though.

Comment: thx. i added an if statement to stop that

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient solution I can think of would involve binary search and a two-pointer approach. Since the array is sorted, we calculate the frequency of the first element in logarithmic time. From here, chunk up the rest of the array in equal sized blocks, and if both:

1. The current block starts with a value not equal to that of the previous block
2. The current block ends with the value it started with.

hold, we can conclude that each distinct value in the array will appear the same number of times. This works only because the array is sorted to begin with.

If `N` is the number of elements in the array and `m`, the number of distinct elements, the runtime is `O(log(N) + m)`.

```
import bisect

def hasSameOccurrenceCount(deck):
    if not deck:
        return True
    deck_length = len(deck)
    # How many times does the first element appear? All other distinct elements must follow.
    expected = bisect.bisect_right(deck, deck[0])
    # Can't even have an even number of groups so break early
    if deck_length % expected != 0:
        return False
    prev_val = deck[0]
    # Iterate on the start of each group of elements
    for idx in range(expected, deck_length, expected):
        curr_val = deck[idx]
        # had > expected number of values of prev_val or less
        if curr_val == prev_val or deck[idx + expected - 1] != curr_val:
            return False
        prev_val = curr_val
        
    return True
    
def main():
    all_passed = True
    for test_array, expected in [
        ([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5], False),
        ([1, 1, 3, 3, 6, 6], True),
        (sorted(list(range(10)) * 7), True),
        (sorted(list(range(10)) * 7 + [6] * 7), False), # 0 appears 7 times so evening out the length to avoid short-circuit
        (sorted(list(range(10)) * 7 + [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]), False)
    ]:
        result = hasSameOccurrenceCount(test_array)
        if result != expected:
            print(f"{test_array} failed; expected {expected}, got {result}")
            all_passed = False
            
    if all_passed:
        print("Passed")
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```